# Wrap file output at given column

Tags: bash, shell

I would need to print the contents of a file (e.g., `cat $file`), but wrap output at a given column width (let's say 80 cols), independently of terminal width.

Is there something in the "standard" Unix arsenal that would give me this functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic tool for doing this is [fold(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fold). For example,

```
fold -s -w 80 $file
```

will fold the lines in $file to fit within 80 columns and break lines at spaces.

Comment: I *knew* there had to be something like that, but couldn't find it... BTW, 80 columns are default already, so a simple `| fold` works perfectly for me. Thanks!